# I need a 4-component vector with components other than 1.0 that sums to an integer or regular magnitude

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I need a 4-component linear algebra vector, with no more than 1 component equal to 1.0, that sums to an integer or regular magnitude/length. By "regular", I mean finite and non-repeating; any decimal ending also needs to be some order of powers of 2. In addition, and to cover all cases, no component should be equal to zero.

The purpose is to ensure that my program is correct, as computers do not always calculate decimal square roots correctly. However, the question itself seems more mathematical than code-related, so I put it here. My apologies if that was incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean that the sum of the elements of the vector is an integer? That should be very easy...

Comment: No, the vector magnitude, ie: (x * x + y * y + z * z + w * w)^0.5

Comment: Is (5,5,5,5) ok?

Comment: Hmm...Sorry, should have covered that. If all of the numbers are the same, the test could return a false positive - If the wrong components are multiplied together, the result will still be the same.

Comment: If you need them to all be distinct, then the vector $(3,4,12,84)$ has magnitude $85$

Comment: Thank you; that worked perfectly. If you post it as an answer, I can upvote and checkmark. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $(3,4,12,84)$ has Euclidean length $\sqrt{3^{2}+4^{2}+12^{2}+84^{2}} = 85$